# Translateable dataobject module Tab

Tags: silverstripe

I'm using silverstripe version 3.1

I tried to add to each DataObject a translation. For that I've used the following module:
https://github.com/bummzack/translatable-dataobject

I would like to have a modeladmin which uses a dataobject in 3 languages. (German, French and English - 3 Tabs)

```
private static $db = array(
    'Title' => 'Varchar(200)'
);

  public function getCMSFields() {

    $fields = new FieldList();
    $fields->add($this->getTranslatableTabSet());
    $fields->removeByName("URLSegment");
    return $fields;
  }
```

How can I add

```
new TextField('Title', 'Titel *', '', 20)
```

in order to be able to define for example the limit of characters of 20?

This example didn't work for me. Only a blank site is shown in the CMS:

```
  public function getCMSFields() {

    $fields = new FieldList(
    new TextField('Title', 'Titel *', '', 20)
    );
    $fields->add($this->getTranslatableTabSet());
    $fields->removeByName("URLSegment");
    return $fields;
  }
```

Any ideas what I did wrong? 
Thank you